# TypeError: NumPy Text File Import

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Text File

[image: Text File]

I'm trying to import the text file above using the following code:

```
 import numpy as np
Climate_data =np.genfromtxt('C:\\Users\\vishv\\Desktop\\Stats With Python\\Stats_with_python\\CSV Files\\Climate Data.txt', delimiter= ',', skip_header='1')
print(Climate_data)
```

But it gives me the following T**ypeError:'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `skip_header` as a string, it [should be an integer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) (`skip_header=1`).

Also, please don't post (even parts of) code as images, it makes it harder to help.

Comment: Thank you! The change worked. And I will keep that tip in mind